# Facebook Page Plugin Error

Tags: facebook, plugins

im trying to use the code that is generated from facebook page plugin and use in my web page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin
as i add facebook page url, my page do not appear in preview.I try in this plugin with other pages and they display correctly on preview.
What might be wrong here?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#privacy: _“Privacy Restricted Pages: Facebook Pages with privacy restrictions cannot be embedded.”_

Comment: Where do i change these setting on my page?

Comment: Page settings. If you need more info on this, please consult the FB Help section.